# jquery output value pass to visualforce

Tags: jquery, salesforce, visualforce

How to pass jquery value result into visualforce code for example:

My jquery code is

```
 $j('[id$=submit]').on("click", function(){
 var output = [], $jselects = $j(".container .row .span6 #form-details select"), i;
 for (i=0; i < $jselects.length; i += 2)
    output.push($jselects.eq(i).find("option:selected").text() +
                ":" + $jselects.eq(i+1).find("option:selected").text());
})
```

When i click this id, the output values are generated like b:b,s:s,a:a This values are stroed in to variable as `output`

Here my visualforce code

```
<apex:commandButton id="submit" action="{!myMethod}" value="Submit" styleClass="btn btn-primary" reRender="block">
  <apex:param name="myParam" value="output"/>
</apex:commandButton>
```

When I press the id `submit`, get the output value from jquery and it will be set in the  place of `output` in `<apex:param name="myParam" value="output"/>` this line.
Here the output text are generated, but I need to know how send that value inside this `<apex>` code.

Is it possible or not...?

Appreciate for your answer...

Answer (score 1):

You have three options

1) Create actionfunction with parameter. Then call the actionfunction and pass the generated string as parameter, just like any other javascript function.

2) Use Javascript remoting. It lets you pass parameters along with method call. But it requires method to be static.

3)Use a hidden `<apex:hiddeninput>` field. Then using javascript set value of this input as your string. Then this will be passed to controller with any regular apex post events(`apex:commandButton or apex:commandLink`)

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a good sample about how pass javascript values to apex methods:

http://blogs.developerforce.com/developer-relations/2009/10/passing-javascript-values-to-apex-controller.html

You should use `apex:actionFunction`

Answer (score 0):

You can use RemoteAction like this: 
in javascript do this:

```
Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
   '{!$RemoteAction.yourController.yourfunction}',your_data,
           function(result, event){
              //the result of your apex code
           }
);
```

in your apex do this:

```
@RemoteAction
public static string yourfunction(String your_data) {

    // do your stuff
    return result;

}
```

Comment: Just to point out this is not an ActionFunction but a RemoteAction, slighly different in their implementations but calling them by the wrong names could get confusing. ActionFunctions are Apex Actions that are exposed as Javascript Functions. RemoteActions are Static Apex Methods that are exposed via a javascript interface so they can be natively handled via javascript